# Change from multiple similar requests with only id changing to only one

Tags: mysql, select

I have the same request executed multiple times with different ID:

```
SELECT n.id 
FROM news n 
JOIN news_tag nt ON r.id=nt.id_news 
WHERE nt.id_tag in (Select t.id_tag from news_tag t where t.id_news=2869) 
ORDER BY r.id DESC 
LIMIT 2
```

This request select the 2 last news that are with the same tags than the given news.

I would like to know how to perform the same request but to get the results for severals IDs in only one request!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical "Top N per group" query, with "B" being **2** in your case.

[Here's a generic solution](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/sql-selecting-top-n-records-per-group) I wrote for N records per group.

Comment: Your article seems to be very clear and corresponding to my question! Thx

Comment: Cool. I was a bit short on this post due to crying baby, and didn't feel I provided with a high quality answer. Glad you found the link helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the IN clause ?

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm

This would do it if i got you right:

```
SELECT n.id 
FROM news n 
JOIN news_tag nt ON r.id=nt.id_news 
WHERE nt.id_tag in (Select t.id_tag from news_tag t where t.id_news IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)) 
ORDER BY r.id DESC 
LIMIT 2
```

where 1,2,3,4 etc are ids of the articles.

Hope this helped.

Comment: May be i' was unclear, but i want for each news to return 2 related news having the same tag. In your code it return the 2 last news related to one of the IDs